# How do I know a a batch of images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript Map kit, and it use Image object to load images. Every time I move/resize the map, it will load many images. But I want to know how I can fire a function when all images are loaded after I do a move/resize action.

Is there a way that I can create a listener like "allimages.onload=function(){}" ?

Or is there any workaround?

Comment: What is a javascript map kit? Any sample code, link to homepage of ?javascript map kit?

Comment: Also: this function that fires when all the images have been loaded, what should it do? Maybe we can help you achieve the same result without implementing such a listener, which would be tricky to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to maintain a count of how many images were yet to load, and call the final function when the outstanding image count reached 0. eg.

```
function nofunction() {}

function loadImages(srcs, callback) {
    var images= [];
    var imagen= srcs.length;
    for (var i= 0; i<srcs.length; i++) {
        var image= new Image();
        image.onload=image.onerror= function() {
            imagen--;
            if (imagen==0) {
                this.onload=this.onerror= nofunction;
                callback();
            }
        };
        image.src= srcs[i];
        images.push(image);
    }
    return images;
}

...

var images= loadImages(['/img/1.gif', '/img/2.gif'], function() {
    alert('yay');
});

for (var i= 0; i<images.length; i++)
    mapelement.appendChild(images[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe this is what I want and I will give it a try soon

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I have written [a blog post](http://blog.valugi.ro/2009/09/11/callback-for-image-loading-with-jquery/) about detecting the load of a single image. You can use the example to build your function that checks if all images are loaded. I hope it will help.